# python: loading numbers from text file to arrays skipping certain entries

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm quit new to programming so I'm sorry to bother you with a very simple question.

I have a .txt of numbers written consecutively (but with spacing). Using python, I would like to create and save arrays of dimension=10 only if they don't have all entries equal to zero.

For example my data.txt is written like this:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 0 7 8 9 0 32 47 5 87 4 65 78 90 94 22 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 2 4 6 5 2 1 4 6 5
```

I want to scan all numbers in the file in sets of 10 (which is the dimension of my vectors), if all entries are zero, then don't save; otherwise save in array of dimension=10.

The result I want to have is

```
a= [1 2 3 4 5 0 7 8 9 0]

b= [32 47 5 87 4 65 78 90 94 22]

c= [3 2 4 6 5 2 1 4 6 5]
```

I then need to use this vectors to calculate the pearson correlation function.

Hope the question is clear.Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: `import array
import numpy as np
import scipy
from scipy.stats.stats import pearsonr
import os

n=10
v2=np.loadtxt('data.txt')
dim=len(v2)/10
split=np.split(v2,dim)

for i in  range(0,dim):
    t=v2[i:n*(i+1)]
    if t !=[0]*10:
        no_zeros=t`

but of course it does not work. Plus I don't want to save all numbers in a vector and then analyze it because the real file that I should deal with has thousands of entries!

Thank you

Comment: Why are the numbers in one long line?  In Python it is easiest to read text files line by line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go. Code has been tested but you'll need to add the reading-from-file part

```
def not_zeroes(arr):
    return any([x!=0 for x in arr])

vectors = []
for line in open('myfile.txt'):

    numbers = list(map(float,line.split()))
    for i in range(0, len(numbers), 10):
        vector = numbers[i:i+10]
        if not_zeroes(vector):
            vectors.append(vector)
print vectors
```

Comment: your input is given from "line", how do I make him read the file that I have without wasting memory??
THank you soooo much!

Comment: what if now my .txt file are numbers, separated by newlines creating different paragraphs. I want python to fill the array up to the dimension that I want (dim=10),even if the following line starts before I finished filling my array, therefore ignoring the newline. How can I modify your previous program?

Answer (score 1):

Step by step in the interactive shell.

Your string:

```
>>> st='0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 0 7 8 9 0 32 47 5 87 4 65 78 90 94 22 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 2 4 6 5 2 1 4 6 5'
```

That string in as a list of integers:

```
>>> map(int, st.split())
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 7, 8, 9, 0, 32, 47, 5, 87, 4, 65, 78, 90, 94, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 4, 6, 5, 2, 1, 4, 6, 5]
```

That list in tuples of 10 ints each:

```
>>> zip(*[iter(map(int, st.split()))]*10)
[(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 7, 8, 9, 0), (32, 47, 5, 87, 4, 65, 78, 90, 94, 22), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (3, 2, 4, 6, 5, 2, 1, 4, 6, 5)]
```

Now filter out the tuples that are just zeros:

```
>>> [t for t in zip(*[iter(map(int, st.split()))]*10) if sum(t)]
[(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 7, 8, 9, 0), (32, 47, 5, 87, 4, 65, 78, 90, 94, 22), (3, 2, 4, 6, 5, 2, 1, 4, 6, 5)]
```

If you want a,b,c to have those values (and you know you have 3 tuples:

```
>>> a,b,c=[t for t in zip(*[iter(map(int, st.split()))]*10) if sum(t)]
>>> a
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 7, 8, 9, 0)
>>> b
(32, 47, 5, 87, 4, 65, 78, 90, 94, 22)
>>> c
(3, 2, 4, 6, 5, 2, 1, 4, 6, 5)
```